# "Add" button stops working after deleting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I'm able to clone the `#ingredient_1` `div` with the <kbd>Add</kbd> button. However, after pressing <kbd>Add</kbd> several times, then deleting random cloned `div`s with their specific <kbd>X</kbd> buttons, the <kbd>Add</kbd> button stops working.

I've replicated this problem across several browsers. Any advice would go a long way.

```js
$('#add_more').click(function() {
  var num = $('.clone').length;

  var newNum = num + 1;

  var newElem = $('#ingredient_1').clone().attr('id', 'ingredient' + '_' + newNum);

  $('#ingredient_' + num).after(newElem);
});

$('#main').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="ingredient_1" class="clone">
    <select id="1">
      <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Amount" />
    <select id="2">
      <option selected="selected">Units</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <select id="3">
      <option selected="selected">Time</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
  <div id="add_button">
    <input type="button" id="add_more" value="Add" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You use the same ID multiple times as you clone things with `id="1"` etc. That’s a huge problem.

Answer (score 3):

Once you delete the first row the element you're cloning no longer exists. Clone the element outside your click function so it's not overwritten:

```
var newElem = $('#ingredient_1').clone().attr('id', 'ingredient' + '_' + newNum);
var num = 1;

$('#add_more').click(function() { ... });
```

Also, declare your ID incrementor outside the function and simply add 1 each time the click function runs with `num++`. I'm guessing that it doesn't really matter what the ID values are, so as long as they're unique this works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `.length` to calculate `newNum`. If you delete DIVs in the middle, you'll end up with duplicate IDs. For instance, suppose you first add 3 DIVs, you'll have DIVs numbered 1, 2, 3, 4. Then you delete #3. The next time you click `Add`, `$(".clone").length` will be `3`, so you'll set `newNum = 4;`. But there's still a DIV with that ID.

Instead of using `$(".clone").length`, get the ID of `$(".clone:last")`, get the number at the end of it, and add 1 to that.

Answer (score 1):

You're cloning, which if you have at least one static item, is fine. I fixed up your code so your initial row is hidden, and you have an ID variable that is auto incremented. On top of which, on load, it creates clones and creates the first row. Your back end code will just have to ignore a case where the style is set to `display:none`.

```
var id = 1;
$(function () {
    var first = $('.clone');
    first.attr('style', 'display:none');
    NewRow();
});

$('#add_more').click(function () {
    NewRow();
});

function NewRow() {
    console.log('num = ' + id++);

    var newElem = $('.clone:last').clone().attr('id', 'ingredient' + '_' + id + '_x');
    newElem.attr('style', '');
    $('.clone:last').after(newElem);
}

$('#main').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

You'll notice that I changed your click event to call the function `NewRow()`, this was done so that you can call a function in the `Document.Ready` event, as well as on the button click.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="ingredient_1" class="clone">
        <select id="1">
            <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Amount" />
        <select id="2">
            <option selected="selected">Units</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
        <select id="3">
            <option selected="selected">Time</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="">Select</option>
        </select>
        <button class="remove">X</button>
    </div>
    <div id="add_button">
        <input type="button" id="add_more" value="Add" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z1x9wsv3/)

Comment: I am so impressed with the quick reply.

Comment: We do what we can around here. Hopefully the code's written clearly enough for you to follow. I left the `console.log` so you can see how the index automatically updates.

Comment: @Matthew Make sure you also select the answer that best suited your needs. It's a great way to say thank you.